# Moodle manager's view options

Tags: php, mysql, moodle

When we have the system role `manager` as user in Moodle, we can see a list of users in `My team`, to whom we are assigned as managers.
But, if they have their own teams, where there are the managers, I as the manager on the top of the pyramid can only see my subordinates and not the people bellow them.

Is there a code snippet, where we can set, which part of the pyramid bellow us we can see?

I looked in `moodle/my/teammembers.php`, but didn't find anything. Just the string `teammembers`, but not where is defined, which parts we can see, if logged as a manager.

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference, `teammembers.php` is Totara code not Moodle code.

Also the `manager` role is similar to the `admin` role but with fewer privileges it isn't related to staff. There is a specific `staffmanager` role in Totara.

The teammembers code displays an embedded report - the report code is here - `/totara/reportbuilder/embedded/rb_team_members_embedded.php`

You'll need to modify `$this->contentsettings` so it displays all staff below the current user.

There are a lot of options for contentsettings. Totara have provided a document called "Developing for Totara Report Builder" which is very useful. But you will need to contact Totara or your Totara partner for a copy.

Comment: Hi Rusell, thanks for the guidance, I managed to do that by configuring the content options in the team members report under `Reports/Report builder/Manage reports`. But, how if I need to add under My Team another report next to one from `/totara/reportbuilder/embedded/rb_team_members_embedded.php`, for example from one of the activity modules (where it is described in `mod/newmodule/rb_sources/rb_source_newmodule.php`?